# Combine 2 XML documents verison 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

We have a program that creates two XML files.  I need to combine the two XML files and have the new XML file automatically go into a hot folder.  I was thinking of using XSLT to do this, but am not certain on how to go about doing it. I have no experience with XML and am looking for some help.  Below is the code I was thinking of using to accomplish the task, but I don't know how to test it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pdoc1Url" select="'XML1.xml'"/>
 <xsl:param name="pdoc2Url" select="'XML2.xml'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <documents>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc1Url)"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($pdoc2Url)"/>
  </documents>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

An XSLT processor needs two things to work with: a stylesheet and a document that it can transform. In your case, you don't have a specific document to transform as you load the two documents using the `document()` function.  But the stylesheet needs a document root (`/`) to match.  So you could do something like

```
xsltproc mystylesheet.xsl mystylesheet.xsl
```

The stylsheet will then match its own document root and apply the template that loads the two documents.

Comment: Ok & thank you. I will give that a try.  Where do I add xsltproc mystylesheet.xsl mystylesheet.xsl

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  What I wrote would be on the command line, assuming xsltproc is installed.

Comment: Well as of right now...it's for a customer and I am not sure.  I am kindof in limbo right now and waiting for information.  I just wanted to get some basic ideas on the project.

Comment: xsltproc is installed... @ Thomas W